# JavaScript appendChild() a with href crashes browser

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

I have this object with a few methods, which crate a new

```
<li><a href="?">http://www.domain.com</a></li>
```

for each link found within the content of the page and appends them to the previously generated

```
<ul id="container"></ul>
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
var linkObject = {
    parseUrl : function(url) {

        "use strict";

        var thisATag = document.createElement('a');
        thisATag.href = url;
        var thisHostName = thisATag.hostname;
        return thisHostName;

    },
    displayLinkContainer : function() {        

        "use strict";

        var thisWrapper = document.getElementById("contentWrapper");

        var thisDiv = document.createElement("div");
        thisDiv.setAttribute('id', 'wrapper');
        thisWrapper.appendChild(thisDiv);

        var thisHeading = document.createElement("h2");
        var thisHeadingTextNode = document.createTextNode("The list of links");
        thisHeading.appendChild(thisHeadingTextNode);
        thisDiv.appendChild(thisHeading);

        var thisUl = document.createElement("ul");
        thisUl.setAttribute('id', 'container');
        thisDiv.appendChild(thisUl);    

    },
    displayLink : function(thisLink, thisActualUrl) {

        "use strict";

        var thisContainer = document.getElementById('container');        
        var thisLiTag = document.createElement('li');
        var thisATag = document.createElement('a');

        thisATag.setAttribute('target', '_blank');        
        thisATag.setAttribute('href', encodeURI(thisActualUrl));    

        var thisTextNode = document.createTextNode(thisLink);

        thisATag.appendChild(thisTextNode);        
        thisLiTag.appendChild(thisATag);        
        thisContainer.appendChild(thisLiTag);

    },
    findLinks : function() {

        "use strict";

        var thisHrefs = [];
        var thisLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

        if (thisLinks.length > 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < thisLinks.length; i++) {

                var thisAHref = thisLinks[i].getAttribute('href');

                if (thisAHref !== '#') {
                    var thisAUrl = linkObject.parseUrl(thisAHref);
                    thisHrefs.push(thisAUrl);
                    linkObject.displayLink(thisAUrl, thisAHref);

                }

            } 
        }
    }
};
linkObject.findLinks();
```

The html :

```
<div id="contentWrapper"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk/">Google</a> <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></div>
```

If I remove the `<a>` tag element creation then it works fine, but when it's run the way it is then the browser gets stuck and crashes. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

After some debugging I've found out that the problem is with **thisActualUrl** as when I comment it and replace with just hash like so:

```
thisATag.setAttribute('href', '#' /* encodeURI(thisActualUrl) */);
```

The code runs ok, but when it runs with thisActualUrl what it does is it displays the links found on the page and then the links to the current page's url on a long loop - crashing browser eventually.

Comment: I can - but I want to complete this one without the use of it.

Comment: It's working here, http://jsfiddle.net/heera/vBHs7/

Comment: Check this too http://jsfiddle.net/heera/vBHs7/2/

Comment: True - it does work - I've updated my original post including the entire object and its methods - perhaps there's something else that's affecting it.

Answer (score -1):

Can't reproduce the error:

http://jsfiddle.net/ENXwY/

so, the problem might be your `thisActualUrl` parameter